# How to include static files from outside the project root in django

Tags: javascript, html, django, static

My structure looks likte this:

```
  conf/
       my_other_script.js         <-- The file I want to include
    project/
      appname/
        static/ 
          appname/  
            my_script.js <-- current script that I include
        views.py
        ...

  templates/    
    base.html

  settings.py
  views.py
```

How do I include `my_other_script.js` in the HTML which is in the `conf` folder on the same level as the `project` folder.

`my_script.js` works like this

`<script type='text/javascript' src="{% static 'appname/my_script.js' %}"></script>`

I tried with `../` but didnt't work. Also, couldn't find anything in the docs anywhere.

Anyone an idea? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the absolute path to that directory in [STATICFILES_DIRS setting](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS). You can calculate from the `settings.py` dir, just add a variable like this:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

And then add the static files path, ie:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.abspath(os.path.join(
        BASE_DIR, '..', 'conf', 'project', 'appname', 'static'))]
```

In production, `collectstatic` will pick it up.

For more info check out [Django's howto manage static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/).

Comment: awesome thnkas, now I finally understood this part too :)

Comment: Try [surviving static files](http://blog.yourlabs.org/post/30382323418/surviving-djangocontribstaticfiles-or-how-to) article too.